# why my android retrofit is returning null? Iam getting other values but this specific api is not getting the value

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

this is my api service code

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
suspend fun login (@Field("username")username:String,@Field("password")password:String):LoggedUser
```

This is the json data which i need

```
 {
     "data": {
    "id": "",
    "emailid": "",
    "pass": "",
    "username": "",
    "profilepic": "",
    "locations": "",
    "favoritefoods": "",
    "favoritecooks": "",
    "rating": ""
    },
   "status": true
    }
```

And Iam using the class

```
  data class LoggedUser(@SerializedName("data")
                  val data: Data,
                  @SerializedName("status")
                  val status: Boolean = false)
```

this is the Data class in the LoggedUser class

```
  data class Data(@SerializedName("favoritefoods")
            val favoritefoods: String = "",
            @SerializedName("favoritecooks")
            val favoritecooks: String = "",
            @SerializedName("pass")
            val pass: String = "",
            @SerializedName("profilepic")
            val profilepic: String = "",
            @SerializedName("rating")
            val rating: String = "",
            @SerializedName("emailid")
            val emailid: String = "",
            @SerializedName("locations")
            val locations: String = "",
            @SerializedName("id")
            val id: String = "",
            @SerializedName("username")
            val username: String = "")
```

The other codes are all clear because i am getting values by using other apis Its the calling fun

```
  fun logier(username:String, password:String):LiveData<LoggedUser> {

  val eulogiser: LiveData<LoggedUser> = liveData {
      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          val data = epicureservices.login(username, password)
          emit(data)
          Log.e("EnteredReplogindata",data.toString())

      }
  }
  Log.e("LoginResult",eulogiser.value.toString())
  return eulogiser
```

}

Comment: You should add the @Expose tag before each SerializedName tag

Comment: Still its returning null

Comment: how do you enqueue your call?

Comment: I have added that code above

Comment: you should build your retrofit client and enqueue the call, check https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: i am using kotlin coroutines livedata here its working for other apis

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#8

Comment: Remove @FormUrlEncoded and try once.

Comment: I tried that too